# displaying all discount code in product page opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I want to display all my discount offers in Product page , Total i have 5 offers in back-end

Here is the code

```
    <?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) { ?>
    <?php echo $discount['quantity']; ?><?php echo $text_discount; ?><?php echo $discount['price']; ?><br />
    <?php } ?
```

But in a result the 1st offer is getting ignored , its starts from 2nd value

[image: price from second]

and the output of array is

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [quantity] => 40 [price] => $5.00 ) [1] => Array ( [quantity] => 160 [price] => $4.00 ) [2] => Array ( [quantity] => 320 [price] => $3.90 ) [3] => Array ( [quantity] => 480 [price] => $3.50 ) )
```

and the back-end setup for offers is

[image: offers]

is there is any way we can display all the offers ?

Comment: what is ` $text_discount?`

Comment: You should check your MySQL query why it got only 4 records instead of 5

Comment: @AntonyMN its 'or more'   please check this link https://www.showoffdisplays.com.au/a4-sign-holder-l-shape-single-sided

Comment: Why not run the entire excerpt on php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change here

```
public function getProductDiscounts($product_id) {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND quantity >= 0 AND ((date_start = '0000-00-00' OR date_start < NOW()) AND (date_end = '0000-00-00' OR date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY quantity ASC, priority ASC, price ASC");

return $query->rows;
```

}

Please change `AND quantity > 1`  to `AND quantity >= 0`

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<-- Other html code -->

<?php
   foreach($discounts as $discount) {
       echo $discount['quantity'] . ' or more '. $discount['price'] .'<br>';   
   }
?>

<-- Other html code -->

</body>
</html>
```